# TypeError: NoneType not callable when debugging Python3 code that uses Cython in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, cython

```
project
|-main.py
|-cythonCode.pyx
```

The `main.py` file imports functions from `cythonCode.pyx`.
Running the program regularly works just fine, but debugging it causes the following Exception:

```
(...)
File "<censored>/project/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cythonCode import *
  File "project/cythonCode.pyx", line 5, in init cythonCode
  File "project/cythonCode.pyx", line 5, in __Pyx_PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cythonCode(void)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is happening? Why can't the debugger work with Cython?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was that the Cython code was compiled using the `linetrace=True` compiler directive, which apparently the debugger does not like (why though? I have no idea). Setting it to `False` solves the issue.

I got my inspiration from [an issue on the Cython github](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1769)

Comment: Thanks, that (nearly) solved this issue for me. I additionally had to manually delete the in-place `*.pyd` files (located at the same place as the source `*.pyx` files) that were created by the `python.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace` command.